# Way to store a Big Hashmap in DirectByteBuffer

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I want to store a hash map (entries upto 1,000,000,000 )in DirectByteBuffer to which i will need to read and write entries. The hashmap will have a string key and serializable object. But if serialize the hash map as a whole and store it as Byte Buffer , every time i need to deserialize it which can cause issues to Heap memory. Is there any other way in which i can store key values in DirectByteBuffer, search for a key and retrieve the value in a optimized way ? 
PS : I need a incache solution and also i need to free the objects (which will be values in my hashmap )from java heap  as their quantity is large.

Comment: *Why* are you trying to store it in a ByteBuffer? Please give more background.

Comment: Its some metadata which should be readily available in the application. i can't put it in db. Also this should be kept away from GC.

Comment: Well given that what goes into a byte buffer is *just bytes*, that's not going to prevent anything from being GC'd. Why can't the metadata just be available via the hash map?

Comment: I have referred DirectByteBuffer which will use physical memory not heap memory...

Comment: In what way is heap memory not physical memory? Either way, you're still not going to be preventing GC...

Comment: DirectByteBuffer stores in OS controlled physical memory which is not allocated to JVM Heap.

Comment: Okay, but that still doesn't prevent anything from being GC'd. Sorry, it's just really unclear what you're trying to achieve and why you need DirectByteBuffer.

Comment: I need a in memory cache and one option i am trying is to have a reference to DirectByteBuffer so only reference keeps in java heap and buffer memory will be in machine's virtual memory. So buffer's memory won't be mixed with JVM Heap memory. That's the whole point. now pls look at my question.

Comment: Nope, I still don't see any reason to use a DirectByteBuffer here. A simple normal map seems a lot simpler, and you haven't clearly explained why that doesn't work for you. Please edit your *question* (rather than just adding comments) around why you think that's a problem, and maybe someone else can help you.

Comment: (It would also help if you said what the key and value types are in the map - that could affect the result very significantly.)

Answer (score 0):

By using a DirectByteBuffer, you're going to be using native memory. Am I correct in assuming that the reason you're going down this path is that you don't want to store 1000000000 in heap memory? If you're concerned about java memory usage, can you just set the max heap size of your JVM to handle this? (i.e. -Xmx )? The net result should be the same and you don't have to worry about native memory. Here's an article that discusses this http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jvm-java-increase-heap-size-setting-heap-size-jvm-heap/

Comment: This way you can keep it in heap memory and keep it as a map. No serialization needed.